# UDP is not reliable at all?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, udp, broadcast

I have designed a system in which i used UDP to send broadcast messages to some clients connected to the same Access point. I am using an Access point to connect the server and all other clients. The problem is with the broadcasting. When i broadcast say a message of 800 bytes to the clients, reception is totally random. Sometimes clients are able to get the messages and sometimes not. I tried to broadcast it multiple times so that at-least one will go through and reach all the clients. But even this is not working some times. Why are packets getting dropped? Any problem with the size of packets ? How should i go about to make it reliable ? What factors may lead to this?
I have 40-50 clients connected to the AP. The Access point is exclusively used for this Application and there is no Internet connection to it.

Comment: UDP is an inherently unreliable protocol, but there could be reasons why it's more unreliable than usual. Do you have some statistics on the actual drop rate?

Comment: I dont have any stats. But its so random. Will datagram size affect the drop rate?

Comment: Likely yes, though 800 bytes is pretty small. Without statistics on the drop rate it's impossible to determine if your losses are expected or out of the ordinary. Wireless links are pretty lossy, but protocols like TCP will compensate for that. UDP is fire and forget.

Comment: I have fired each packet 5 times and its 90% reliable. Is it the correct way to do it or is there any other way to work around?

Comment: You're not going to get absolute reliability that way, but sure, if the drop rates are OK for you in that case, that's one method. Otherwise you'd need some sort of acknowledgement in your protocol, or just do TCP.

Comment: I would be more concerned with the rate of sending packets. If you do not introduce intervals between packets being sent your drop rate would be normally higher. And anyway, why don't you use multicast? in my experience it would work smoother than broadcast, but I never tried it with wifi AP.

Comment: 40-50 clients on a single AP?  That's too many!  You're at the upper limit of what you can do.  Even if you're all standing in the same room, there will definitely be trouble and packet loss.

Comment: Actually i am making a quizzing application for a classroom. I can put a repeater AP in the classroom. Assuming no one is using any network application and internet is not connected to the AP. @Brad

Comment: @wick Ya, i did gave an interval between the packets.

Comment: Broadcast (and multicast) over WiFi simply doesn't work well:  http://superuser.com/questions/695813/wifi-udp-unicast-vs-multicast-speed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDP is inherently unreliable in the sense that:

- UDP packets *may* be lost, and
- the UDP protocol provides no mechanism to tell if packets have been lost, or to resend them.

> Why are packets getting dropped?

In general, there are a number of possible reasons:

- packets may be misrouted,
- packets may be "eaten" by a firewall,
- packets may be dropped due to congestion in a gateway,
- packets may be dropped due to congestion at the end-point, or
- packets may be lost due to a network-level problem; e.g. a collision or a transmission error.

> Any problem with the size of packets?

Yes.  If a UDP packet is too large, it may need to be fragmented (at the IP packet level).  If any of the fragments gets lost, then the receiver cannot reassemble the packet, and the entire UDP packet will be lost.  (There is no mechanism for retransmitting the lost fragments.)

Reference:  http://pcvr.nl/tcpip/udp_user.htm#11.

Hence, the probability of a large UDP packet getting lost is greater.

Note that fragmentation occurs when the IP packet size exceeds the MTU of a link.  For an Ethernet link, the MTU is typically ~1500 octets or more.  But the IPv4 spec allows the MTU to be as low as 576 octets.  If you subtract the size of the IP and UDP headers, that gives a minimum UDP packet payload size of 534 octets before fragmentation is possible.

> How should i go about to make it reliable ?

These things *may* help:

- Pick a maximum UDP packet size that won't lead to fragmentation.
- Implement your software to read the packets as quickly as possible ... to avoid the packets being dropped by the receiving OS.
- Avoid sending UDP packets through a (potentially) congested network link.
- Avoid sending too many packets in too short a time.

But nothing will make UDP reliable in the sense above.  The protocol is inherently unreliable.  If you want reliability, either use TCP or implement your own reliability mechanisms at the application protocol level.  The former is probably the better approach.

Comment: Your link says packets > MTU are fragmented (which on Ethernet typically, as in your link, is 1500), where do you get 534 bytes from?

Comment: @markmnl - the minimum required MTU for an IP packet is 576.  Deduct the UDP/IP header sizes ...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have solved it by sending an acknowledgement for every packet and retrying until the packet gets through with a 500 ms delay between them. It is working better than the naive approach.

Comment: Does the OS drop the packets, if we delay for some time to receive them on a UDP Port?

Comment: I don't think it would.  But it would drop UDP messages if kernel buffering for the socket was exceeded; i.e. if you had too many unread messages.